# Google Maps not displaying in Qt WebView, other sites work

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I just picked up Qt and QML for the first time and the first thing I wanted to get working was just to open Google Maps in a WebView but it doesn’t work.

Here’s the QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0

Rectangle {
    width: 1024
    height: 960
    WebView {
        width: 1024
        height: 960
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        url: "http://maps.google.com"
    }
 }
```

The window opens but the contents of the WebView are completely blank. If I try other websites then the correct web page is displayed.

What’s wrong with this code? I am not behind any proxy or firewall. I suspect it is something to do with HTTPS given that some maps APIs use HTTPS but I don’t see why HTTP would work but not HTTPS.

I am using Qt 5.1 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: It might have to do with the redirect (the http url gives a 302 to the https url), or perhaps because the page uses javascript to render *everything*, and the webview's javascript engine has a problem with some of the code...

Comment: Is there anyone out there who can get it to work in their environment?  I would like to establish whether it's something peculiar to my set-up.

Comment: Do you use GCC or VS? The GCC version needs to be able to find the SSL libraries included in the distribution. It should work if you run directly from QTCreator, but might not find those libraries otherwise.